# Is it possible to "merge" the values of multiple records into a single field without using a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2005

A co-worker posed this question to me, and I told them, "No, you'll need to write a sproc for that".  But I thought I'd give them a chance and put this out to the community.

Essentially, they have a table with keys mapping to multiple values.  For a report, they want to aggregate on the key and "mash" all of the values into a single field.  Here's a visual:

```
---  -------
Key  Value
---  -------
1    A
1    B
1    C
2    X
2    Y
```

The result would be as follows:

```
---  -------
Key  Value
---  -------
1    A,B,C
2    X,Y
```

They need this in SQLServer 2005.  Again, I think they need to write a stored procedure, but if anyone knows a magic out-of-the-box function that does this, I'd be impressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if sql-server supports group_concat - but that's what you would use in MySQL:

```
SELECT key, GROUP_CONCAT(value) FROM table_name GROUP BY key
```

I use this all the time.

Also to add to this GROUP_CONCAT by default will separate  value using commas, but you can format it any way you want - interjecting text, calculations or values from other columns.

Comment: Sweet!  I just found a posting that is a SQL Server 2005 port for this: http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html

Comment: I'm been missing this for reporting scenarios in SQL Server for as long as I can remember. It would however advice against it for any purpose other than presenting information in a manner that is CSV. This is for instance not a solution for packing multiple things into a single column.

Comment: j0rd4n - apparently there is no easy way to do it - so you can try your port - or you can try this SO answer as well - they all emulate GROUP_CONCAT  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005

Comment: @j0rd4n: I shiver at the very sight of `FOR XML PATH('')` doesn't that look wrong or completely misguided use of the XML support that exists in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: John - you are absolutely right - that is what it I use this for - - this is a much more elegant solution in my humble opinion - than trying to get a load of  data an process it  in your code - since this is faster - but it should only be used to retrieve and present data - not do any modifications with it, as the benefit of the speed would be lost by the complexity of the parsing code.

Comment: @John Leidegren - Yes, I agree.  I commented that link without reading the full thing.  Does feel a bit dirty I admit.  I might not do that in production.  I think I'm going to still recommend a sproc.